# how to traslate ok and cancel button for message box into other language in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

here is the question , for i want to change some text for "ok" and "cancel" button,

instead of "ok" button, i want to write in other language and also for cancel button

something like this :

```
[OK] Đồng ý
[Cancel] Hủy
```

what i used is default code :

```
if (MessageBox.Show("We are redirecting to our youtube channel?", "", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                {

                }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom message box using XNA DLLs. The list of allowed namespaces is in [XNA Framework and Windows Phone 8 development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207003%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). You need to add `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameServices` assembly in your project. You will notice that the `Guide` class of that assembly has method called [`BeginShowMessageBox(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940233.aspx). You can use it to customize the message box. Below is full code.

```
IAsyncResult result = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.Guide.BeginShowMessageBox(
"",
"We are redirecting to our youtube channel?",
new string[] { "Đồng ý", "Hủy" },
0,
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.MessageBoxIcon.None,
null,
null);

result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

int? choice = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.Guide.EndShowMessageBox(result);
if(choice.HasValue)
{
    if(choice.Value == 0)
    {
         //User clicks on the first button
    }
}
```

Source : [Advanced MessageBox for Windows Phone](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Advanced_MessageBox_for_Windows_Phone)

Moreover you can also create a user control which acts like a custom message box, check out [Creating a Custom MessageBox for Windows Phone Applications](http://visuallylocated.com/post/2011/11/13/Creating-a-Custom-MessageBox-for-Windows-Phone-Applications.aspx)

TCD.Controls also has CustomMessageBox.

[NuGet for TCD.Controls](https://nuget.org/packages/TCD.Controls)

[A Custom (Async) MessageBox for WPF and Windows Phone using TCD.Controls](http://kuchenzeit.wordpress.com/2013/09/06/a-custom-async-messagebox-for-wpf-and-windows-phone/)

Comment: Then you should not use `windows-phone-8` tag.

Answer (score 0):

The incentive of using the `MessageBox` class as opposed to implementing your own functionality is that the text resources for the control are pulled from the system at run-time. This means that if the phone is set to be in another language, the message box control will match that language.

This means that the phone will have to be configured to be in Vietnamese instead of English, which is a lot less work :)

For strings that you create ( as opposed to the `MessageBox` string in this example) , you can provide definitions for the String in whatever language you want, and then change the phone's default language setting. 
 
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637520(v=vs.105).aspx